# Spring Boot Actuator endpoint to report trace information of HTTP trace information for requests to OAuth Endpoints

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot-actuator

I have a spring application with spring security that is bootstrapped to use OIDC login flow. The spring application has an end point that's protected and i am invoking the end point by passing the JWT token as a bearer token in the header. I have the Spring Boot Actuator endpoints enabled so that I am able to view HTTP trace information, but I am only receiving the request to the custom endpoint that I mapped in a controller. I am not receiving HTTP trace information on requests to the OAuth `/authorize` or `/token` endpoints. I would like to know the time spent by Spring Security to validate the JWT token.

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72454764/spring-boot-actuator-not-reporting-http-trace-information-for-requests-to-spring) that I followed, but the `/httptrace` endpoint has been removed since then and I am unfamiliar with filter ordering. If there is another solution that has since been integrated, any information would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

/httptrace endpoint is renamed to /httpexchanges